# How to set the state from other component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to set the state from the functional component to App component. Buts it is giving error.  Please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

// APP Component

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    onPasswordChange = (text) => {
        console.log("text: ", text);
        this.setState({name:text})
    } 

    onNameChange = (text) => {
        console.log("text: ", text);
    }

    state = {
        name: "",
        password:""
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <SafeAreaView style = {styles.container}>
            <TextField placeholder = "Email"  onTextChange = {(text) => this.onNameChange(text)}/>
            <TextField placeholder = "Password" isSecure = {true} onTextChange = {(text) => this.onPasswordChange(text)}/>
            <ButtonNormal title = "Login" onTouched = {()=> this.onPress()} />
        </SafeAreaView>
           );
         };
}
```

// TextField Component.

```
const TextField = (props) => {
    return (
    <TextInput placeholder = {props.placeholder} style = {Styles.textField} secureTextEntry={props.isSecure} onChangeText={(text) => props.onTextChange(text) }/>
    );
};
```

[image: Error showing like this.]

Comment: bind the function since you're using `this`.

Comment: show error please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't fire the function in child component, since you're not adding additional data to it ro manipulating the data before it gets set. just set the function from the prop because its already bound from the parents arrow function.

```
const TextField = (props) => {
    return (
    <TextInput placeholder = {props.placeholder} style = {Styles.textField} secureTextEntry={props.isSecure} onChangeText={props.onTextChange}/>
    );
};
```